# connection string is not working with my database on Microsoft SQL Server in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have this on my web.config file

```
<add name="EFDBContext"
 connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=StadinPeli;
 Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And yes in Server Explorer in visual studio 2012 professional edition, it works with
`EFDBContext (WebUI)`.
But its the wrong database. Somehow this `EFDBContext` database copy its definitions from the database where I want it to connect all the time,
which is `jon-pc\localdb#13158683.StadinPeli.dbo`.

I checked properties from `jon-pc\localdb#13158683.StadinPeli.dbo` for its connection string
but it still connects to `EFDBContext (WebUI)`.

Where is the problem, I have tried to correct this for 3 hours already.

Answer (score 0):

(Localdb) as data source is probably wrong.  Try updating it to (local) so your connection string looks like this

```
<add name="EFDBContext"
connectionString="Data Source=(local)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=StadinPeli;
Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```